# How do I make an efficient lookup table?

Tags: solidity

I need a 110-length lookup table that stores numbers from 1 to 20.

I think the solution might be to move the instruction pointer forward by the index, and then return. Is something like this possible? For example:

```
JumpForward index
return 1
return 2
return 2
etc...
```

Following are what I've tried so far, compiling with optimizations on:

**A table in memory** - 3086 gas

```
function lookup(uint256 index) private pure returns (uint256) {

    uint8[110] memory bellCurveTable = [
         1,
         2, 2,
         3, 3, 3,
         4, 4, 4, 4,
         5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
         6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
         7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
         8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
         9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
        10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,
        11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,
        12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,12,
        13,13,13,13,13,13,13,13,
        14,14,14,14,14,14,14,
        15,15,15,15,15,15,
        16,16,16,16,16,
        17,17,17,17,
        18,18,18,
        19,19,
        20
    ];

    return bellCurveTable[index];
}
```

**An if-else chain** - 45 to 449 gas

```
function lookup(uint256 index) private pure returns (uint256) {
    if      (index <=   0) return  0;
    else if (index <=   2) return  1;
    else if (index <=   5) return  2;
    else if (index <=   9) return  3;
    else if (index <=  14) return  4;
    else if (index <=  20) return  5;
    else if (index <=  27) return  6;
    else if (index <=  35) return  7;
    else if (index <=  44) return  8;
    else if (index <=  54) return  9;
    else if (index <=  65) return 10;
    else if (index <=  76) return 11;
    else if (index <=  86) return 12;
    else if (index <=  95) return 13;
    else if (index <= 103) return 14;
    else if (index <= 110) return 15;
    else if (index <= 116) return 16;
    else if (index <= 121) return 17;
    else if (index <= 125) return 18;
    else if (index <= 128) return 19;
    else                   return 20;
}
```

**An assembly switch statement** - 94 to 2445 gas (estimated)

```
function lookup(uint256 index) private pure returns (uint256 stat) {
    assembly {
        switch index
        case   0 { stat :=  0 }
        case   1 { stat :=  1 }
        case   2 { stat :=  1 }
        case   3 { stat :=  2 }
        case   4 { stat :=  2 }
        case   5 { stat :=  2 }
        case   6 { stat :=  3 }
        case   7 { stat :=  3 }
        case   8 { stat :=  3 }
        case   9 { stat :=  3 }
        case  10 { stat :=  4 }
        case  11 { stat :=  4 }
        case  12 { stat :=  4 }
        case  13 { stat :=  4 }
        case  14 { stat :=  4 }
        case  15 { stat :=  5 }
        case  16 { stat :=  5 }
        case  17 { stat :=  5 }
        case  18 { stat :=  5 }
        case  19 { stat :=  5 }
        // etc...
        default  { stat := 20 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, I found a decent way. But I'm sure there are methods that cost less gas. I'd still appreciate further help.

**Using a string constant** - 139 gas

```
string constant bellCurveTable = "\
A\
BB\
CCC\
DDDD\
EEEEE\
FFFFFF\
GGGGGGG\
HHHHHHHH\
IIIIIIIII\
JJJJJJJJJJ\
KKKKKKKKKK\
LLLLLLLLLL\
MMMMMMMMM\
NNNNNNNN\
OOOOOOO\
PPPPPP\
QQQQQ\
RRRR\
SSS\
TT\
U\
";

function lookupString(uint256 index) public pure returns (uint256) {
    bytes memory bellCurveTableBytes = bytes(bellCurveTable);
    return uint256(bellCurveTableBytes[index]) - 64;
}
```

Comment: I think is not gonna be better than this. Also, from a practical point of view 139 gas is nothing.

Comment: An option is to store the curve data as bytes directly (ie `bytes constant bellCurveTable = hex"00010202030303...";`), but you will only save the subtraction of 64 at the end.

Comment: Thanks, Ismael. That lowered the gas cost down to 83, from 139.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
function lookup (uint256 index) public pure returns (uint256) {
    return uint8 (bytes (hex"0102020303030404040405050505050606060606060707070707070708080808080808080909090909090909090a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0a0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0b0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0c0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0d0e0e0e0e0e0e0e0f0f0f0f0f0f101010101011111111121212131314") [index]);
}
```

** note the [index] at the end of this long line.*